Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' .Getting this error while working with setup of Dagger 2
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
I am getting this issue while setting Building the project while working with setup of Dagger 2
My Project Setup
Dependencies in build.gradle.kts:
dependencies {      
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40.5")      
kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5")      
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.40.5")      
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.40.5")     
kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.40.5") 
}
Dagger Setup:
class UserRegistrationService @Inject constructor( 
private val userRepository: UserRepository,
private val emailService: EmailService) 
{ 
internal fun registerUser(email: String, password: String) {      
emailService.send(email, "ShivsagarLenin@gmail.com", "User Registered")  
}
}

@Component
interface UserRegistrationComponent {
fun getUserRegistrationService(): UserRegistrationService
}

Issue:
After syncing the project successfully, I tried rebuilding the project to get val userRegistration=DaggerUserRegistrationComponent.builder().build().getUserRegistrationService(), but I am encountering the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

What I Have Tried:

Ensuring that all dependencies are correctly added.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio.
Instead of  kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5") in dependencies, I tried
annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5"), using this project rebuild is successful, but unable to get DaggerUserRegistrationComponent.builder().build().getUserRegistrationService()

